# Questions marked as duplicate but have higher visiblity than the original

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

Sometimes I see questions marked as duplicated but actually they have a better keywords in title so they are better indexed by google and visits are way higher than original. I actually have an answer to a question which has 30+ upvote and the question itself has 6 upvotes, way more than the one linked as duplicate of. This might be due a better question's title which makes it more relevant than the original. How should we handle this cases? Shall those question being reopened?

Comment: Which question is better, as in clearer and more concise? That's the one which should be the master. Though if the margin is minor, and there are good answers on the current master, don't bother. Anyway, might a merge make sense, to get all aswers to the better master? Perhaps only after clarifying that it actually *is* an *exact duplicate*?

Comment: @Deduplicator You probably did missunderstand my question. It's not a matter of what is the "master" question nor the "master" answer. Both or more could exist! That's what i meant. And by the way, if noon has passed the day after will still be the correct one.

Comment: DST means that a day gains or looses one hour. So, in the first hour of the day after DST begins, 24h earlier is not the first hour of the previous day, but the last of the one before that. (I don't know how that interacts with php in that answer, though I guess the asker wanted only the previous day.)

Comment: @Deduplicator Well this depends on how the server handle the DST, it's not a matter of pramming language though. The time is given by the server!

Comment: There are also places in the world where DST doesn't exist, you might want to check China or Brazil for example. Your comment is really unhelpfull

Comment: Thinking more about DST your comment is even False, for example in italy the DST happens at 3 am so loosing one hour won't really affect the changing of the day.

Comment: The fact that there are time-zones without DST does not change anything. And if you look at my comment, the important part was that the day had one hour less or more than 24. It does not matter at what time DST takes effect.

Comment: Still false. If  time changes the server will handle that. There is no time lag anywhere, i mean, if the time changes because of dts the day before will be still correct. I really don't see your point. You still immagine a day of 25 hours which will never exist, it's just a matter of changing clock during the night and that won't ever affect any calculation. Sorry if i still don't get your point.